# Read HDF5 data with numpy axis order with Julia HDF5

Tags: julia, hdf5

I have an HDF5 file containing arrays that are saved with Python/numpy. When I read them into Julia using HDF5.jl, the axes are in the reverse of the order in which they appear in Python. To reduce the mental gymnastics involved in moving between the Python and Julia codebases, I reverse the axis order when I read the data into Julia. I have written my own function to do this:

```
function reversedims(ary::Array)
  permutedims(ary, [ ndims(ary):-1:1 ])
end

data = HDF5.read(someh5file, somekey) |> reversedims
```

This is not ideal because (1) I always have to import reversedims to use this; (2) I have to remember to do this for each `Array` I read. I am wondering if it is possible to either:

- instruct HDF5.jl to read in the arrays with a numpy-style axis order, either through a keyword argument or some kind of global configuration parameter
- use a builtin single argument function to reverse the axes

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to create a H5py.jl package, modeled on MAT.jl (which reads and writes .mat files created by Matlab). See also https://github.com/timholy/HDF5.jl/issues/180.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like [permutedims!](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/#Base.permutedims!) does what you're looking for, however it does do an array copy. If you can rewrite the hdf5 files in python, [numpy.asfortranarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asfortranarray.html) claims to return your data stored in column-major format, though the [numpy internals docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html) seem to suggest that the data isn't altered, simply the stride is, so I don't know if the hdf5 file output would be any different

**Edit:** Sorry, I just saw you are already using `permutedims` in your function. I couldn't find anything else on the Julia side, but I would still try the `numpy.asfortranarray` and see if that helps.

Comment: Alternatively, you could reverse the strides of your array, which has the same disadvantages you mentioned (have to remember to do it every time, etc), but it does avoid the memory copy

Comment: Thanks-- doesn't my current solution implement what you propose in your comment though? I don't think `permutedims` (version with no `!`) does an array copy. And isn't changing the strides what it means to permute the dimensions? Maybe I'm confused.

Comment: @SeanMackesey you're right, I was rushed when I answered and should have noticed the regular `permutedims` function. I was looking at [this](https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl/pull/85) thread and saw that a way to avoid the permutedims call was to reorder the strides and dimensions. Whether this has any benefit to the non-copy permutedims is questionable. This is just the nature of languages with different internal array structures, you have to convert on one side or another. Were you able to try the `numpy.asfortranarray`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, as I have collaborators using the same Python codebase who might not appreciate me switching the axis order of the output... It is good to know that numpy has this option though.

Comment: @SeanMackesey,  You could always request that the developers of HDF5.jl add an argument to switch the axes order. Otherwise, I'm out of suggestions. Sorry